# start ur5 remotely

Tags: ros, universal-robot, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Users and UR Users,
is there a way to start UR5 remotely? My main purpose is to save energy on a mobile platform where UR5 is mounted on.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264837/start-ur5-remotely/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2017-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-27**:
Can you be a bit more specific? Are you talking about shutting down / turning on the UR controller, or about the (various) ROS drivers?

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2017-06-27**:
I was searching a method to power on the arm when controller is already on. Actually, I found it possible through the UR Dashboard

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-27**:
Ok, good to hear.

Could I ask you to post a slightly more extensive answer (like: which URScript/Dashboard commands did you use) and then accept your own answer? That will mark the question as answered much more than if you close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Universal Robot provides a Dashboard to manage these kind of commands (power on, power off, ...)
More details are explained here: https://www.universal-robots.com/how-tos-and-faqs/how-to/ur-how-tos/dashboard-server-port-29999-15690/

---

Originally posted by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) with karma: 133 on 2017-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0